# fadeTo() gives unpleasant flashes

Tags: jquery, wordpress

since I updated my wordpress to *3.9 smith*, the following code doesn't work anymore as expected.

```
function mkTitle(_id)
{
    var prjct = $('#allProjects > #'+_id);
    var prjctTitle = $('#allProjects > #'+_id+' > #project-text > #project-title').html();
    prjct.append('<div class="titleSlide">'+ prjctTitle +'</div>');
    $('#allProjects > #'+_id +' > div.titleSlide').fadeTo(0,0); // actual problem
}

function mkVisible()
{
    newPrj = $('#allProjects').find('div#'+_hashCore);
    newPrjTtl = newPrj.find('div.titleSlide');

    newPrj.show().addClass('visiblePost');
    animFlag = false;
    newPrjTtl.finish().fadeTo(0, 0);
    if( newPrj.hasClass('singleProject') == true ){
     newPrjTtl.stop().fadeTo(2000, 1).fadeTo(2000, 0, function(){ // also problem
         slidesAreAnimating = false;
         });
    }
}
```

I see before the animation starts and shortly after a short flash or blinking of `newPrjTtl`. This stands just as an example, I have the same problem all over the site.

Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Comment: how can i see it in action ?

Comment: at my site http://larserbach.com/ - - takes a while to load, sorry for that.
wordpress seems to run fine.. I have it running in Dev-mode and it doesnt give any errors.

Comment: i like it , great !! except that everything is really flickering , doesnt sound like a script issue though , did it work well in previous wp version ? if so i may check the change log for you.

Comment: ohh Thanks a lot! Yes, worked perfect before. Where do you find the change log?

Comment: what version did you used before ?

Comment: ok let me check please

Comment: im not wp expert , but do you see anything here : http://make.wordpress.org/core/tag/3.9/  , that may cause this problem ?

Comment: I'd be surprised. I dont use any widgets. I register few scripts in funcion.php and that's it. ..Maybe I should move on to wordpress support?

Answer (score 0):

ok before you contact the wp support i want to suggest a solution that may work :

```
function mkTitle(_id)
{
    var prjct = $('#allProjects > #'+_id);
    var prjctTitle = $('#allProjects > #'+_id+' > #project-text > #project-title').html();
    prjct.append('<div style='display:hidden' class="titleSlide">'+ prjctTitle +'</div>');
    $('#allProjects > #'+_id +' > div.titleSlide').fadeTo(0,0); // actual problem
    $('#allProjects > #'+_id +' > div.titleSlide').show();
}

function mkVisible()
{
    newPrj = $('#allProjects').find('div#'+_hashCore);
    newPrjTtl = newPrj.find('div.titleSlide');

    newPrj.show().addClass('visiblePost');
    animFlag = false;
    newPrjTtl.finish().fadeTo(0, 0);
    if( newPrj.hasClass('singleProject') == true ){
     newPrjTtl.stop().fadeTo(2000, 1, function(){ // also problem
         slidesAreAnimating = false;
         });
    }
}
```

Comment: will try it in a minute

Comment: and it does somehow help.. but the problem now is, that the title stays solid, because we left out the second `.fadeTo(2000, 0, function()`.

Comment: yes i removed this function cause i didnt understand what it is for , would you explain what you wanna do with this part exactly?

Comment: `newPrjTtl.stop().fadeTo(2000, 1).fadeTo(2000, 0, function()` fades in the title, afterwards fades it out again. When both animations are finished I set my flag `slidesAreAnimating` to false.

Comment: I need the flag to control the scrolling behaviour

Comment: Thanks anyways, I own you a drink.

Comment: :) just let me know if it works please , maybe i can help some way else.

Comment: I think I solved it. I just deregistered the script _jQuery Easing v1.3_ and voilà the flickering is gone! To bad I actually liked the script.

Comment: ok just some advice stay away from using jquery animations and stick to css native ones , much faster , much better  performance , however if you still want to use jquery animation then use transit instead : http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/

Comment: Yes, you are totally right. The idea of using css came up during process. Now I'm a bit to lazy to change it :)
And transit looks interesting, I'll take a closer look.